# Is it possible to upload a private root certificate to an Arduino Nano33?

Tags: arduino-nano, wifi, mqtt, arduino-nano-33-iot

I'm trying to connect an Arduino Nano 33 to an `mqtt broker` with TLS authenticaton on the broker side. To do that I need my Arduino board to have access to the the `root` certificate.

My understanding is that unlike ESP32, the Nano's NINA wifi module does not have a `WiFiSSLClient` object with a `setCACert` method that you can use to pass the root certificate. Instead, the NINA's client has a `connectSSL()` method which uses whatever root certificate you have uploaded to the Nano using Arduino's IDE. However, as it can bee seen in this [tutorial](https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/360016119219-How-to-add-certificates-to-Wifi-Nina-Wifi-101-Modules-), it looks like it is only possible to upload public domain root certificates by entering the website.

But what if I wanted to upload a `root` certificate that I have generated using OpenSSL. Would that be possible?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiNINAFirmwareUpdater#certificate-uploading